# ViewModel into View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Currently I'm learning C# with WPF. My mainapproach is to use the MVVM pattern the best I can but now I'm a bit confused.

In my Application for all my views I have a viewmodel:

```
private DruckviewViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

public Druckview()
{
    ViewModel = new DruckviewViewModel();
    DataContext = ViewModel;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Is this the suggested way to implement the ViewModel into the View or are there better ways to do it?

Comment: Is this way working as you expecting?

Comment: Feel free to stop by the WPF chat room. We do MVVM. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: @Fabio yes, it is working pretty well. But on every website there is the speaking of "zero-codebehind", so I thought there must be a other way

Comment: MVVM != no codebehind.  And your code here has a massive smell.  It appears you're putting UI code in view models designed specifically for user controls.  A user control can be designed for a view model, or for a model, but not the other way around.  Think about this--does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  No.  To do so would break how bindings work.  DataContext wouldn't be your model/view model, and so `<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeVmProperty}` would fail.

Comment: @F.Baum: That is called *view-first*, and it **sucks**.

Comment: @H.B. why? Can you explain it a Little?

Comment: @Will but in my App, I can take a Property of my ViewModel and bind it to e.g. a Text of a Textbox

Comment: @F.Baum: WPF is not designed for it, it only causes trouble, especially when dealing with lists, where you have to do a lot of manual wiring to get the view-created view-model back into the parent view-model. The logic is simply backwards. Also, implicit `DataTemplates` are another thing that only works nicely with **view-model first**.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling time.  It's not on my side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVVM doesn't mean no code-behind.

MVVM is the pattern of separation of concerns. It helps to separate your application's architecture to the three parts(in order of appearance):
    `Model`
    `View`
    `ViewModel`

Where `Model` is class containing your business logic.

`View` represents your view class which contains only view related logic(`XAML` and `code-behind`)  It is Ok to have code-behind unless code contains only view's logic (*for example in button click eventhandler you copy color of one textbox to another, which of course can be done in `XAML`, but from `MVVM` point of view it is not important*)

`ViewModel` represents View's behavior without any reference to the `View`.
Notice that for example this property on my opinion will violate `MVVM` pattern, because `Visibility` is view related type

```
public Visibility MyVisibility { get; set; }
```

So dependencies between parts of `MVVM` goes like this:

`Model` doesn't know about anything
`ViewModel` know only about `Model`
`View` know about `ViewModel`

View ---> ViewModel ---> Model

I think for using `MVVM` is not important how tightly `View` bounded to the `ViewModel`. It is already bounded, because you use `ViewModel`'s properties and commands.

Not bounding tightly (for example using interface as `ViewModel`) will give your possibility to test View without real `ViewModel` by creating own "design-time" viewmodels for example.

If your current solution works and satisfy your needs and you just starting with `MVVM` and `WPF` then continue with that until you meet need to fully isolate `View` from `ViewModel`'s types

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but it isn't really true to the MVVM pattern, as the View is now directly tied to the View Model.

Most existing MVVM frameworks use the concept of a View Manager.  A class that creates a view from a view model instance, connects them together, and displays the view. You would end up with something like this:

```
DruckviewViewModel vm = new DruckviewViewModel()
ViewManager.Instance.DisplayViewFor(vm);
```

It would figure out, based on naming conventions, that `DruckviewViewModel` uses the `Druckview`.  It would create the view, set the DataContextProperty, and make the view visible.

Without using one of these frameworks, this is a lot of work to build on your own, but this is considered a "Best Practice" pattern.

You may want to consider using an existing framework, a good list comparing their features can be found [here](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CTL/MVVM+framework+comparison+sheet).

---

BTW, if you are wondering how to get intellisense in the XAML designer without setting the DataContext in the constructor of the view. The proper way to do it is to add a design instance in XAML, with an attribute like this.

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:DruckviewViewModel}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation! I think I'm gonna use some framework for this.. I'm a trainee at a software company and everytime I have to write some Code, my bosses are like 'hey, think about the MVVM pattern because of my codebehind'.

Comment: I think how tightly `View` bounded to the `ViewModel` is not related to `MVVM` pattern, because `View` need to know about `ViewModel` at least in runtime. Of course, relieving this connection will give more possibilities in designing View and using of this.

Comment: Views don't need to know about a specific View Model though.  they only need to know the basic "shape".  You can have a view that will work with many different kinds of View Models, even ones that don't share ancestry.  But you can't do that if you have a property on the View declared as a specific concrete type.